# VBA - Expect Expression / AdvancedFilter, CopyToRange

Tags: excel, vba

```
sub Unique_Values()

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("name").Activate
Range("J:J").AdvancedFilter_
Action:=xlFilterCopy,
CopyToRange:=_
Range("BO:BO"), Unique:=True
End Sub
```

it always submits me that the expression is missing.

I dont know why.

Does anyone know?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You have the line continuation characters and commas in the wrong positions.

```
Sub Unique_Values()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("name").Activate
    Range("J:J").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                                CopyToRange:=Range("BO:BO"), _
                                Unique:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) i just know the importance of indention regarding Python. Except my wrong commas its important that Action:= is written within the row in which the actual action ( Range"").AdvancedFilter) happens?